# Handling Date Comparison in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to pull back records that have a birthday in a particular month, of a certain membership type, who are active AND have checked into the facility within the last 30 days. But I am having difficulty with the 30 logic. Every way that I attempt to calculate the date the query in MS SQL errors out.

I keep getting a syntax error related to the date calcualtion.

```
SELECT 
MEMBERS.scancode, MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.dob, 
MEMBERS.status, MEMBERTYPES.description, MEMBERS.mtypeid, 
SITES.sitename, MEMBERS.email
FROM MEMBERS 
INNER JOIN SITES ON MEMBERS.siteid = SITES.siteid 
INNER JOIN MEMBERTYPES ON MEMBERS.mtypeid = MEMBERTYPES.mtypeid
WHERE (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite) 
AND (MEMBERS.status = 'A') 
AND (MONTH(MEMBERS.dob) = @rvMonth) 
AND (MEMBERS.relationship = 'M') 
AND (MEMBERS.mtypeid IN (1, 10, 12, 22, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 40, 48)) 
AND (DATEDIFF(MEMBERS.lastvisit, GETDATE()) <= 30)
```

Comment: Ccan you please share the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function requires 3 arguments `datepart , startdate , enddate`. You were missing the first argument (datepart) in the query. Change it to

```
DATEDIFF(DD,MEMBERS.lastvisit, GETDATE()) <= 30
```

Comment: Oh man, missed that in the documentation. You rock, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would do here is to change up this logic a little bit because when you wrap a column inside a function it is no longer SARGable so any indexes on that column are useless.

Here is another way of writing this query that is SARGable.

```
MEMBER.lastvisit <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```